# Plotly Express hover options

Tags: python, hover, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-express

In `plotly_express.line` the only options I see to modify hover settings are `hover_name` and `hover_data`. A few issues I'm facing with modifying hover are:

1. It seems that even if I set `hover_data=None` it still shows the values for `name`,`x`, and `y`. How can I set it to *only* show the hover info I select without adding defaults?
2. I can't find a setting to modify the opacity for hover boxes. I'm displaying a lot of hover info so my hover box is large, which makes it difficult to know where I am on the plot behind the box.
3. How can I make it so hovering on one line displays hover info corresponding to a linked data column value on all other lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 and 2 are not possible yet.

For 3 there is a `hovermode` attribute in `layout` that you can set to show one hover label per trace per y-value.

Comment: Thanks. Does it happen to be possible to lock the hover box to a predefined location?

Comment: There’s no feature for that, no.

Comment: For hovermode, I see that there's `x` and `y` options, but can we use an arbitrary dataframe column instead? For example, I'm plotting precision-recall curves, and I'd like to see matching values of the "detection_threshold" parameter column on other lines while hovering.

Comment: @Austin if you want to break that out into its own question I’d be happy to help you find an answer

Comment: Sure, thanks. Here's a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57525950/plotly-express-hovermode-with-arbitrary-column