# Plotly Express hovermode with arbitrary column

Tags: python, hover, plotly, plotly-python, plotly-express

I see that the `hovermode` attribute in `layout` has options for `x` or `y`, but is it possible to use an arbitrary dataframe column? instead?

For example, I'm plotting precision-recall curves. The x-axis is recall, and the y-axis is precision. The independent variable is a detection threshold value (with range of `np.linspace(0,1.0,101)`) with a column in my dataframe called `threshold`. When I hover over a precision-recall point, what I'm interested in is points on other curves with the same detection threshold value. So can I instead hover on this column?

Comment: So you have multiple precision-recall curves in this context?

Comment: Yes, one for each class label, and then a micro-averaged curve as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there’s no feature for that at the moment. You could consider a second set of “iso-threshold” curves to see this kind of thing perhaps?

Comment: I have been considering iso-threshold curves, although the downsides are clutter (one of the reasons I wanted to use interactive plots in the first place) and needing to deselect/select two matching legend items for each.